# dynamic partitioning a table in hive for a given column from existing table

Tags: hive

"Details" table which contains Name, Age and Date columns.

create table Details(Name String,Age int, Date String)

row format delimited fields terminated by ','

stored as textfile;

Name Age Date

aa 11 2012-04-06

bb 12 2012-04-06

cc 13 2013-02-10

dd 14 2013-02-10

ee 15 2013-02-10

ff 16 2014-04-01

gg 17 2014-04-01

hh 18 2014-04-01

ii 19 2014-04-01

jj 20 2014-04-01

How to insert the data into "Person" table by dynamic partitioning using Date column from "Details" table.

In the above scenario it must contain 3 partitions with data as

2012-04-06

2014-04-01

2014-04-01

Answer (score 0):

hive> create table Person (Name String,Age int) partitioned by (date string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',';

hive> insert into table Person partition(date) select name,age,date from Details;

Comment: also make sure     hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;